# Downgrade Windows 8 Pro to Windows 8 Home?

Tags: windows-8, license

I have a trial version of Windows 8 Professional that expires in February 2014. For my usage Windows 8 or Windows 8 Core versions are enough. It it possible to downgrade it to the normal non-Professional version of Windows 8 when I buy it officially? Do I have to re-install it completely or do I only have to enter the new registration code?

Comment: A Windows Professional installation will not accept a Windows Core license. The same is true with `Windows 8 Professional Media Center` not accepting a Windows 8 Professional license.  This limit isn't actually new.  Windows 7 Professional would not accept accept lower versions of Windows 7 either.

Comment: @magicandre you don't need to sprinkle `code formatting` all over the place. Just use it for places where you actually have code, commands, or other text that actually needs to be monospaced.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this small tool called [UpDown8](http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/36726-UpDown8-Windows-8-Upgrade-Downgrade-Helper).

Select which edition you want to downgrade:

[image: UpDown8 screenshot]

and click `ok`. Now insert the Windows 8 Core Edition DVD, run `setup.exe` and select `Upgrade`. This downgrades Win8 Pro WMC to Core.

Comment: Forum is not working anymore (cannot register), but I found download link for UpdDown8: http://www.datafilehost.com/d/8d1ceb8c